# Using pyplot in different versions always yields "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a simple plot using matplotlib.pyplot package.
I keep getting this error no matter what input I give the function.
This happens even with tutorial input like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

The error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3352, in plot
    ax = gca()
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 969, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1844, in gca
    return self.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1257, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 77, in __init__
    self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 511, in __init__
    self._init_axis()
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 619, in _init_axis
    self.xaxis = maxis.XAxis(self)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 732, in __init__
    self.cla()
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 806, in cla
    self._set_scale('linear')
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 772, in _set_scale
    self._scale.set_default_locators_and_formatters(self)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 73, in set_default_locators_and_formatters
    axis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 2504, in __init__
    MaxNLocator.__init__(self, nbins=nbins, steps=steps)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 1850, in __init__
    self.set_params(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 1900, in set_params
    self._steps = self._validate_steps(steps)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\envs\***\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 1858, in _validate_steps
    if np.any(np.diff(steps) <= 0):
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

I tried using different versions of numpy and matplotlib with no avail.
My current versions are:

```
matplotlib                2.2.3            py37hd159220_0
numpy                     1.11.3          py37h35d8231_12
numpy-base                1.11.3          py37hc3f5095_12
```

I couldn't find a proper solution to this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: The problem comes from part of your code you do not show here. Close PyCharm. Reopen. Make a new py file with just the two lines in it - it will sure work.

Comment: It does work, but it doesn't tell me what's wrong with my current file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, which involved using a built-in function namespace as a variable name.